# Virtual server hosting newbie questions

Tags: virtualization, reseller

I'm searching for a hosting that would suit my needs.
Currently I'm on shared hosting and as my web sites count grows bigger I think I need a better hosting. I think a dedicated hosting is a overkill so I'm going with a virtual server.

I am a newbie in this area and have a few questions:

1. Do virtual servers provide reseller account, so I can provide a cpanel account to my customers so that they can for example manage email addresses themselves?
2. Can I install anything like SVN support on them?
3. Can you recommend some hosting plans, my bandwidth is around 5GB monthly, cheap ones preferably.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not a virtual server provides a control panel to end user  or reseller is not a function of the virtual server itself, this just provides the (virtualised) hardware, and the OS to run on it. If you want to offer CPanel, you will need to get Cpanel installed on your virtual server. Many hosts will do this, and often offer it at minimal cost.

If you get a virtual server, you will get root, or administrator access to the server via SSH or RDP (depending on whether it is Linux or Windows). Therefore you can install whatever you like on it (with some exceptions that may have issues running on virtualised hardware, SVN is not one of these).

As for recommendations of actual hosts, your probably better of looking at [webhostingtalk.com](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/) for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been pretty happy with [dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com) for hosting - as for email control pan... take a look a google hosted email (its free, simular to gMail but you use your own domain name)